# replacing living room light switch with dimmer

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

my living room ceiling light switch has this pattern
there are 2 black wires that come in and out. the switch itself has 2 points where these black wires can be connected
[image]

Here is how the target switch looks like.

[image]

Can I can i just put both the black wires  them together to the same bk screw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing switch is not installed correctly.  Switches must be grounded for safety and it is required by code.  There's also a safety concern with the use of push-in ("backstab") connections which are unreliable and unprofessional.

On the "target" switch, the picture is very small and I can't tell if the holes are for push-in or screw clamping.  Regardless, I would procure a new wire nut and about 6" of black wire, splice it to the other two black wires, and attach the loose end to the switch.  This is sometimes called a pigtail.

Leave the "3-way" screw empty.

Make sure there is a green or bare pigtail attached to the green screw and spliced to the 2 bare wires in the box.  Also ensure the bare wires are not in contact with the white wires in the existing wire nut.  From the photo, I can't tell if those are safely arranged or not.